# Cannot check if a file is all empty

Tags: c#

I need to check if a file contains all white spaced, I have a configuration file that sometimes is damaged with a lot of white spaces, what I tried for now is this:

```
bool damaged = false;

var lines = File.ReadLines("file.config");
foreach (var line in lines)
{
   if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
   {
       damaged = true;
       break;
   }
}
```

if I put a breakpoint on the condition I get:

[image]

but the code doesn't enter in the condition to set `damaged = true` why?